# Get relational data in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

In CakePHP 2.4.1, I am trying to pull data from `table_1` and `table_2` to populate my edit form. I can populate everything except the multiple select box (doesn't select all the rows).

```
map_table
+--------------+--------+
| `table_1_id` | int(5) |
| `table_2_id` | int(5) |
+--------------+--------+

table_1
+--------+--------------+
| `id`   | int(5)       |
| `name` | varchar(100) |
+--------+--------------+

table_2
+--------+--------------+
| `id`   | int(5)       |
| `name` | varchar(100) |
| `url`  | varchar(100) |
+--------+--------------+

/**
 * Class MapTableModel
 */
class MapTableModel extends AppModel
{
    public $name      = 'MapTableModel';
    public $useTable  = 'map_table';
    public $useLegacy = true;

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Table1Model' => array(
            'className' => 'Table1Model',
            'foreignKey' => 'id'
        ),
        'Table2Model' => array(
            'className' => 'Table2Model',
            'foreignKey' => 'id'
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Class Table1Model
 */
class Table1Model extends AppModel
{
    public $name      = 'Table1Model';
    public $useTable  = 'table_1';
    public $useLegacy = true;

    public $hasOne = array(
        'MapTableModel' => array(
            'className' => 'MapTableModel',
            'foreignKey' => 'table_1_id'
        ),
    );
}

/**
 * Class Table2Model
 */
class Table2Model extends AppModel
{
    public $name      = 'Table2Model';
    public $useTable  = 'table_2';
    public $useLegacy = true;

    public $hasMany = array(
        'MapTableModel' => array(
            'className' => 'MapTableModel',
            'foreignKey' => 'table_2_id'
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Class Table1Controller
 */
class Table1Controller extends AdminController
{
    public function add($id = null)
    {
        if(empty($this->request->data))
        {
            # TODO: How do I get the table from Table1Model and
            $dataArray = $this->Table1Model->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array('Table1Model.id' => $id)
            ));
            $this->request->data = $dataArray;
            var_dump($this->request->data);exit;
            # Result:
            /*
            Array
            (
                [Table1Model] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 25
                        [name] => test1
                    )

                [MapTableModel] => Array
                    (
                        [table_1_id] => 25
                        [table_2_id] => 1
                    )

            )
            */

            $dataArray = $this->Table1Model->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array('Table1Model.id' => $id)
            ));
            $this->request->data = $dataArray;
            var_dump($this->request->data);exit;
            # Result:
            /*
            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [Table1Model] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 25
                                [name] => test1
                            )

                        [MapTableModel] => Array
                            (
                                [table_1_id] => 25
                                [table_2_id] => 1
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [Table1Model] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 25
                                [name] => test1
                            )

                        [MapTableModel] => Array
                            (
                                [table_1_id] => 25
                                [table_2_id] => 2
                            )

                    )

            )
            */
        }
        else
        {
            # Has any form data been POSTed?
            if($this->request->is('post'))
            {
                # If the form data can be validated and saved...
                if($this->Table1Model->save($this->request->data))
                {
                    $this->request->data['MapTableModel']['table_1_id'] = $this->Table1Model->id;

                    if(!empty($this->request->data['MapTableModel']['table_2_id']))
                    {
                        # TODO: Better way to do this?
                        foreach($this->request->data['MapTableModel']['table_2_id'] as $table_2_id)
                        {
                            $this->Table1Model->MapTableModel->create();
                            $this->Table1Model->MapTableModel->save(array('table_1_id' => $this->Table1Model->id, 'table_2_id' => $table_2_id));
                            $this->Table1Model->MapTableModel->clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $this->loadModel('Table1Model');
        $table2Results = $this->Table1Model->find('all');
        foreach($table2Results as $table2Data)
        {
            $table2Array[$table2Data['Table1Model']['id']] = $table2Data['Table1Model']['name'];
        }
        # Sort alphabetically.
        ksort($table2Array);
        $this->set('allTable2', $table2Array);
    }
}

/**
 * Class Table2Controller
 */
class Table2Controller extends AdminController
{

}

<?php echo $this->Form->create('Table1Model'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id'); ?>
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <?php echo $this->Form->input(
                    'name',
                    array(
                        'class' => 'form-control'
                    )
                ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Add'); ?>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <?php echo $this->Form->label('Table2'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->select(
                'MapTableModel.table_2_id',
                $allTable2,
                array(
                    'multiple' => true,
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                )
            ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Comment: as you are using custom html to make the form instead of the cakephp form helper, it works well for the input type="text" etc fields but for the select boxes etc you will have to use them as in custom php ie, for every option check whether the value is in_array and if it is then echo selected="selected", as what cake form helper does is it keeps a hidden field as well but as we are not using that so you will have to use the custom approach.

Comment: @RohitAilani I am using CakePHP's form helper. I changed out the straight HTML with the .ctp code.

Comment: Ok so you need to pass the selected array to the multiple select and also change the select to input only. You should check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492031/cakephp-2-0-select-form-mulitple-selected